# debugging an Xbox 360 game?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xna, xbox360

What is the correct Visual Studio setup for developing/debugging an Xbox 360 game under Windows?

I don't have an Xbox at hand all the time, so I have to be able to debug the game under Windows and on the Xbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create an XNA game for any platform Visual Studio can create projects of the game for any of the other supported platforms. That way it is easy to run your Xbox game on Windows. The code base is shared among the projects. You can switch between the different projects by using the "set as startup project feature".

However, keep in mind that some parts of the code will be specific to the given platform and the platforms themselves behave differently as well, so it will not be a fully featured debugging experience. In other words there will be issues that cannot easily be debugging unless you run on the specific platform.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [discussion](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/27613.aspx):

> If you want to start debugging the Xbox 360 project when you press F5, you need to make that project the startup project. To make the Xbox 360 project the startup project, right-click on the Xbox 360 project in Solution Explorer and choose "Set as Startup Project".
>
> After doing this, you just press F5 to start debugging the Xbox 360 project, the same as a Windows project